# Problems with symfony form to save data

Tags: forms, symfony

I started learning Symfony2 and I'm doing a form for entering dates. When I try to save the date I receive:

An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO date (date, critical) VALUES (?, ?)' with params [null, null]:

SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'date' cannot be null .

The class Date is here:

class Date {

```
/**
 *
 * @ORM\Id
 *
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 *
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
protected $id_date;

/**
 *
 * @ORM\Column(type = "date")
 */
protected $date;

/**
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="critical", type="boolean")
 */
protected $critical;

/**
 *
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity = "Category", mappedBy ="date")
 */
protected $categories;
```

In the form type:

class DateType extends AbstractType {

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
    $builder->add('date');
    $builder->add('critical');
    $builder->add('save', 'submit');        
}

public function getName() {
    return 'date';
}

public function getCritical() {
    return 'critical';
}

public function getDefaultOptions(array $options) {
    return array(
        'data_class' => 'GuardBundle\Entity\Date',
    );
}
```

In the controller:

```
public function gesDateAction(Request $request) {
    $date = new Date();
    $form = $this->createForm(new DateType(), $date);
    if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST') {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($date);
        $em->flush();
        return $this->render('GuardBundle:Dates:gesDates.html.twig', array(
                    'form' => $form->createView()));
    }
    return $this->render('GuardBundle:Fechas:gesDates.html.twig', array(
                'form' => $form->createView()));
}
```

In the view:

```
<form action="ges_date" method="post" {{ form_enctype(form) }}>    
    <br>
    {{ form_row(form.date) }}
    {{ form_row(form.critical) }}
    {{ form_row(form.save) }}   
    <br>
</form>
```

Please help me and thank you so much

Comment: maybe you send post request with initial Date Object. So your Date Object is null when you persist entity. read the cookbook http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/direct_submit.html and probably with handleRequest, it should works :)

Answer (score 0):

You are not telling the form to "handle" the current request. So you are creating the form with your entity, then checking the request method is `POST`, then jumping straight to persisting your entity. It's a quick change in your controller:

```
public function gesDateAction(Request $request) {
    $date = new Date();
    $form = $this->createForm(new DateType(), $date);
    if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST') {
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($date);
            $em->flush();
            return $this->render('GuardBundle:Dates:gesDates.html.twig', array(
                    'form' => $form->createView()));
        }
    }

    return $this->render('GuardBundle:Fechas:gesDates.html.twig', array(
            'form' => $form->createView()));
}
```

I've also added a `$form->isValid()` check as if you add constraints to your entity this will catch them.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that you are not using handleRequest() :

**Request Handling**
The handleRequest() method was introduced in Symfony 2.3.
To process form data, you'll need to call the handleRequest() method:

1
$form->handleRequest();

You can find more information on :
http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/form/introduction.html